# How do I use dynamic variables in the xaml files?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm having some issues with binding in the xaml file of my Windows Phone 7 application, and I'm not sure where the issue is..I start with a button that should pass through a text parameter:

```
<Button Content="More Info" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="top40button" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216" FontSize="11" Click="top40button_click" />
```

And here is the method on the click of the button:

```
    private void top40button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/views/songpage.xaml?songname=test", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Then I have this in the cs file for the songpage.xaml file:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string songname = NavigationContext.QueryString["songname"];
    }
```

And I'm not sure how to proceed here, I've tried binding it into the page title, but it hasn't worked, how do I actually get the variable (test at this point) into my xaml file?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding songname}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable songname should be in the ViewModel if you want to bind it. And it should be a property of that ViewModel.

In your code, the best thing to do right now is to set the title directly:

```
PageTitle.Text = songname;
```